# How to convert large .rdf file to .n3 format

Tags: python, python-2.7, rdf

I want to convert .rdf file (of 1 TeraByte) to .n3 format. I wrote my own parser but it is very inefficient (takes 10 days and more). Can someone please suggest me some good library in python, which I may use to accomplish this. Also if possible please point me to some good examples which me help me understand and use the library

Comment: This is probably off topic, since “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.”

Comment: You might have better luck with this on http://answers.semanticweb.com .  **Edit:** it appears that this has already been [crossposted there](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24519/how-to-convert-large-rdf-file-to-n3-format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [cwm](http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/doc/cwm.html),

```
python cwm.py --rdf source-file.rdf --n3 > target-file.n3
```